# Having JSON dump all of a value in a dictionary, not just one value?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, printing

I have been tearing my hair out over this small thing. All I want to do is use `json.dump` to print a set of key and values to a file in a nested list. However, whenever I make the key or value the variable in the JSON nested list, it will only dump one value. For example these are *the_dictionary* items:

```
the_dictionary = {'iphone 3G': 2008, 'iphone 4S': 2011, 'iphone 3GS': 2009, 
                  'iphone 5': 2012, 'iphone 4': 2010}



import json 
for k,v in the_dictionary.items():
    model = (k)
    year = (v)
MY = {}
MY['Stuff'].append({
    "Model": (model),
    "Year": (year),
})
with open('file.txt', 'a+') as f:
    json.dump(MY, f, indent=3, ensure_ascii=False)
```

`

Yet when it prints to file.txt, all I get is something like...

```
`"Stuff":[
    {
        "Model:" "iphone 3G",
        "Year:" "2008"
    }
)`
```

I want *all* of the models and years printed to this file. What do I do to make this work? Convert to a list and then put the list in JSON, or will it do the exact same thing?

Thank you in advance. This was my first ever StackOverflow post, so my apologies if I missed out anything. I'm also pretty new to Python and JSON, so that didn't help me writing this post!

Comment: What is `BT`? I don't see it defined. You also keep overwriting `model` and `year` in your `for` loop.

Comment: your My dict contains only one item. Also, can you show how your json looks like

Comment: There also is no module called `JSON`, did you mean `import json`?

Comment: 1. Fixed the BT, that should have been MY. 2. Why does it contain only one item? I put multiple items into the dictionary. The JSON is everything between MY = {} and `})` 3. All I'm trying to do is show that I am using JSON. Every thing works on this except for this one small thing. I know it's not GREAT code, but it is what I have.

Comment: why do you open a file as 'a+'?

Comment: That is so `file.txt` can be appended to, and if it is not made, make it, hence the `+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initailize your dict object before the loop Otherwise you will be overwriting the same object.

```
import json    
MY['Stuff']=[]
for k,v in the_dictionary.items():
    model = (k)
    year = (v)

    MY['Stuff'].append({
        "Model": (model),
        "Year": (year)
    })
print(MY)
print(json.dumps(MY))
```

Output:

```
'{"Stuff": [{"Model": "iphone 4S", "Year": 2011}, {"Model": "iphone5", "Year": 2012}, {"Model": "iphone 3GS", "Year": 2009}, {"Model": "iphone 4", "Year": 2010}, {"Model": "iphone 3G", "Year": 2008}, {"Model": "iphone 4S", "Year": 2011}]}'
```

Then you can write it to a file

```
with open('file.txt', 'a+') as f:
    json.dump(MY, f, indent=3, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: resulat in KeyError in python 3.6.  
    untitled1.py", line 7, in <module>
    MY['Stuff'].append({

KeyError: 'Stuff'

Comment: Did not paste the initialization stuff. Good catch :)

Comment: Solves the OP question, but hope he can resort to a much simplier data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You take an appraoch when you create bits of a json then wrte it to file, if you really want it - keep file access in one loop, otherwise you just add last value after loop ends.

This may be an excercise, but anything close to real use of dictionaries and a JSON would require create a dictionary, then dump it all to json.

The more meanfil part in your code seems this:

```
import json 
models_dict = {'3G': 2008, 
               '4S': 2011, 
              '3GS': 2009, 
                '5': 2012, 
                '4': 2010}


with open('models.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(models_dict, f, indent=3, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: That would work well, but I guess I should have disclosed that I wanted to print the key and value separately, so I can add more information if I get it later.

Comment: Hmm... you can do the long way or play with a nested structure, but imho `MY` adds no useful information, format or functionality to models_dict, also it risks being overextended when you write into file several times. Perhaps you have some other task in mind (eg make a list of cell phones in stock), where you need another dict, as for models, you know... you are not doing a meaningful thing, as least it does not lookthat way.